# Removing part of a String^ in MFC C++

Tags: string, c++-cli

So far I've only written console applications. My first application using MFC (in Visual Studio 2010) is basically a form with two multiline boxes (using String[] arrays noted with String^) and a button to activate text processing. It should search the String^ for a [, look for the ] behind it and delete all characters between them (including the []). With 'normal' C++ strings, this isn't difficult. String^ however is more like an object and MSDN tells me to make use of the Remove method. So, I tried to implement it.

```
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }
    String^ DestroyCoords(String^ phrase)
    {
        int CoordsStart = 0;
        int CoordsEnd = 0;
        int CharCount = 0;
        for each (Char ch in phrase)
        {
            if (ch == '[')
                CoordsStart = CharCount;
            if (ch == ']')
            {
                CoordsEnd = CharCount;
                //CoordsEnd = phrase->IndexOf(ch);
                phrase->Remove( CoordsStart , CoordsEnd-CoordsStart );
            }
            CharCount++;
        }
    return phrase;
    }
```

The button using the method:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
             TempString = String::Copy(BoxInput->Text);
             DestroyCoords(TempString);
             BoxOutput->Text = TempString;
```

The function seems to hit the correct places at the correct time, but the phrase->Remove() method is doing absolutely nothing..
I'm no OO hero (as said, I normally only build console applications), so it's probably a rookie mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that this is C++/CLI, not MFC. `System::String^` is the .NET String type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++/CLI, `System::String` is immutable, so `Remove` creates a new `String^`.  This means you'll need to assign the results:

```
phrase = phrase->Remove( CoordsStart , CoordsEnd-CoordsStart );
```

The same is true in your usage:

```
TempString = DestroyCoords(TempString);
BoxOutput->Text = TempString;
```

Note that this will still not work, as you'd need to iterate through your string in reverse (as the index will be wrong after the first removal).

Comment: That's the right way to call `Remove` in general, but there's no right way to call `Remove` while iterating the string.

Comment: @BenVoigt True - Would be better to rework the entire algorithm here.

Comment: You're right, I have to input the result back in the original (or any other variable) to prevent losing it. This did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

No MFC here, that's the C++/CLI that Microsoft uses for writing .NET programs in C++.

The .NET `System::String` class is immutable, so any operations you expect to modify the string actually return a new string with the adjustment made.

A further problem is that you're trying to modify a container (the string) while iterating through it.  Instead of using `Remove`, have a `StringBuilder` variable and copy across the parts of the string you want to keep.  This means only a single copy and will be far faster than repeated calls to `Remove` each of which makes a copy.  And it won't interfere with iteration.

Here's the right approach:

```
    int BracketDepth = 0;
    StringBuilder sb(phrase->Length); // using stack semantics
                                      // preallocated to size of input string
    for each (Char ch in phrase)
    {
        if (ch == '[') {              // now we're handling nested brackets
            ++BracketDepth;
        }
        else if (ch == ']') {         // and complaining if there are too many closing brackets
            if (!BracketDepth--) throw gcnew Exception();
        }
        else if (!BracketDepth) {     // keep what's not brackets or inside brackets
            sb.Append(ch);
        }
    }
    if (BracketDepth) throw gcnew Exception(); // not enough closing brackets
    return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: I found out my way only found the first occurence and neglected the rest. I replaced the CharCount construction with proper index methods: 'CoordsStart = phrase->IndexOf(ch);'